# use array item as selector object

Tags: jquery, arrays

i'm messing around with arrays and have a very basic question.
lets say i have this html-markup:

```
<div id="1" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #ff0; display: none;"></div>
<div id="2" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #ffc; display: none;"></div>
<div id="3" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #fcc; display: none;"></div>
```

and create the following array:

```
var testArr = ['$("#1")', '$("#2")', '$("#3")'];
```

why i cant execute the following function to work:

```
 function showArr() { testArr[2].show(); 
  };
 showArr();
```

therefore shouldn't `#3` get displayed?

thanks

Comment: This generally isn't the way to do this. You select all the elements like `var elems = $('#1, #2, #3')` and then based on the order in the DOM you select what to show, like `elems.eq(2).show()`, you don't stick elements in an array unless you have a really good reason to do so, and this doesn't look like it is such a reason. And you shouldn't use just a number for ID's.

Comment: yea, but i only made that for understanding arrays. its not like i want to store selector into arrays. its just that i was trying out, and understand how they work!

Comment: If you stored *just* the `id`s in the array, you could use the (fairly-horrible) approach here: [(horrible) demo (don't seriously consider using this)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fNZCn/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This won't work because you're attempting to run a function on a string.

`testArr[2]` is `'$("#3")'`. Not a jQuery object: it is a string that contains code. So `testArr[2].show()` means `'$("#3")'.show()`. Since strings don't have a `show` method, this won't work.

You need to store jQuery objects, not strings:

```
var testArr = [$("#1"), $("#2"), $("#3")];
```

Comment: thanks for explanation, i'm learning and people like you help me alot! works fine!

Comment: or you can store selectors in array - `var testArr = ["#1", "#2", "#3"];` and then use in jQuery object - `$(testArr[2]).show();`

Answer (score 1):

First off, ids can't start with numbers. Secondly, dont store it as a string, just store the object.

```
testArr = [ $('#item-1'), $('#item-2') ];
```

Comment: Under HTML5 they *can* (but they're an absolute nuisance to select in CSS if they do...).

Comment: why shouldn't i use numbers as `id`? Worked always fine for me!

Comment: @supersize: try using CSS to style `#1`, and then tell me it works 'fine.'

Comment: works pretty good! just kidding, you got me, thanks for the hint... ive never realised this!